# How to change the maintheme color in .net Maui?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, xamarin, maui

I want to change the purple color in a .net Maui app to another one, but I don't know where it is initialized. I already changed primary color in the resources folder, but nothing changed. In the two examples below you can see which colors I mean. I know the option to create a complete custom tool, but I just want to change this color nothing else.

[image: Item: Picker]

[image: Item: Picker]

[image: Item: Entry | meant is the automatic underlined part from the app]

I hope you understand what I want to say. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: When you say you "changed the primary color in resources folder", do you mean the "Primary" color in `Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml` or the "colorPrimary" in `Platforms/Android/Resources/values/colors.xml` ?  Try altering both and see if that works for you.  

It looks like you're using dark theme so make sure to update the colorPrimaryDark too

Comment: How do you change the primary color in the resources folder? You'd better post relevant code on that step to your question which is helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: @AceGambit thank you. I must had to change the color.xml in Andorid ressources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credits: AceGambit
You must have to change the color in Platforms/Android/Resources/values/colors.xml